# what is the right way to use this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this code is for countdown plug in for coming soon page. how can i write this code in short way or right way ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    else if(month == 2){
        var currentMo = 2564;
    }else if(month == 3){
        var currentMo = 452136;
    }else if(month == 4){
        var currentMo = 86985;
    }else if(month == 5){
        var currentMo = 1236;
    }else if(month == 6){
        var currentMo = 12365;
    }else if(month == 7){
        var currentMo = 12546;
    }
});
```

Comment: where is if block?

Comment: Why not use epoch/timestamp for the end date, check against current timestamp and have a setTimeout function updating it?

Comment: There is no initial if, there is no clue on what those numbers mean, there is a lot of missing code, there is no indication on how month is calculated. How are people supposed to answer?

Comment: how can i use timestamp or epoch ? help me out please. 
thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `switch` statement here:

```
var currentMo;
switch (month) {
  case 1:
    currentMo = 1337;
    break;
  case 2:
    currentMo = 2564;
    break;
  case 3:
    currentMo = 452136;
    break;
  // ...
}
```

or even some array with predefined values:

```
var months = [1337, 2564, 452136];
var currentMo = months[month - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to write in short,

```
$(function() {
    var currentMo;
    if(month == 1)
       currentMo  = 2564;
    else if(month == 2)
        currentMo  = 2564;
    else if(month == 3)
        currentMo = 452136;
    else if(month == 4)
        currentMo = 86985;
    else if(month == 5)
        currentMo = 1236;
    else if(month == 6)
        currentMo = 12365;
    else if(month == 7)
        currentMo = 12546;    
});
```